# How to know my directory's path in chrome os linux python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium, google-chrome-os

I'm using chrome book.
I installed linux ,miniconda, and jupyter in chrome OS
I want to use selenium. selenium need chrome webdriver. But I can't find the directory path that contain chromedriver.exe
What can I do? (sorry to my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

```
os.getcwd()
```

should get you current working directory.

try placing your Chrome driver in your current project.

**Imports :**

```
import os
```

Comment: These are in same directory(/home/dgchrome304/). But It doesn't recognize.

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook in linux in chrome os. Just like you said, I find current working directory and I checkecd python file and chromedriver.exe are in same place. So I typed like this

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/home/dgchrome304/chromedriver.exe')`

But It didn't work and printed Permission Error...
I think this is right path but permission is problem now.